# start_info.lpDesktop is LPWSTR entity, but it says this is const wchat_t*?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am a complete noob using C++, i just want to re-compile an exploit.

I got the error:

> you can not assign a value of type "const wchar_t *" to an entity of type "LPWSTR"

[image: The error]

Comment: Please always post text rather than images of text.

Comment: `LPWSTR` is defined as `wchar_t*`, versus `const wchar_t*`. The error says you can't change a constant to mutable.

Comment: Post a [mcve] or there's not really anything we can do to help you.

Comment: They've been cracking down on such practices in VS2017.  You can get the old behavior with Project > Properties > C/C++ > Language, "Conformance mode" = No.  Or use wcscpy_s() to conform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `lpDesktop` field is a `LPWSTR` (`wchar_t*`), not a `LPCWSTR` (`const wchar_t *`). A wide string literal is a `const wchar_t[N]` (where `N` is 16 in your example), which decays to `const wchar_t *`. You cannot assign a pointer-to-const-data to a pointer-to-non-const-data. That is what the compiler is complaining about.

To assign a string literal to `lpDesktop`, you need to cast it:

```
start_info.lpDesktop = (LPWSTR) L"WinSta0\\Default";
```

Or better:

```
start_info.lpDesktop = const_cast<LPWSTR>(L"WinSta0\\Default");
```

Otherwise, copy the data to a local non-const `wchar_t[]` buffer and use that instead:

```
WCHAR szDesktop[] = L"WinSta0\\Default";
start_info.lpDesktop = szDesktop;
```